# How to just print the UID of RFID in Python Arduino

Tags: python, arduino

- I am trying to implement a card system using `RFID-RC522`, Arduino and RFID cards.
- I am able to print the information from the RFID tags, but how can I just print the `UID` of the card and not the whole information in python?
- Code

```
import serial 
import time

device = '/dev/ttyACM0' #this will have to be changed to the serial port you are using
try:
  print("Trying...",device)
  arduino = serial.Serial(device, 9600) 
except: 
  print("Failed to connect on",device)
while True:
    data=arduino.readline()
    pieces=data.splitlines()[0]
    print("Card UID=", pieces)
```

- The above code gives me output as

```
Trying... /dev/ttyACM0
Card UID= b'Firmware Version: 0x92 = v2.0'
Card UID= b'Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks...'
Card UID= b'Card UID: 09 DF 98 B3'
Card UID= b'Card SAK: 08'
Card UID= b'PICC type: MIFARE 1KB'
Card UID= b'Sector Block   0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9 10 11  12 13 14 15  AccessBits'
Card UID= b'  15     63   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] '
Card UID= b'         62   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] '
Card UID= b'         61   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] '
Card UID= b'         60   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] '
```

Comment: `if pieces.startswith("Card UID"): print(pieces.split(":")[1])`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki this gives error ```File "ardu.py", line 14, in <module>
    if pieces.startswith("Card UID"): 
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str```

Comment: You need the `b`: `pieces.startswith(b"Card UID")`

Comment: @Timus still gives error ```File "ardu.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(pieces.split(":")[1])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```

Comment: Imho same mistake: `b":"` instead of `":"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` with multiline `re.M` and grouping. The `data.decode()` decodes the binary data to string - represented by the letter `b` in front of the binary data.

```
>>> import re
>>> data = b"""Firmware Version: 0x92 = v2.0
... Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks...
... Card UID: 09 DF 98 B3
... Card SAK: 08
... PICC type: MIFARE 1KB
... Sector Block   0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9 10 11  12 13 14 15  AccessBits
...   15     63   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ]
...          62   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ]
...          61   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ]
...          60   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ]"""
>>> for line in data.splitlines():
...     try:
...         card_uid = re.search('(?<=Card UID: ).*', line.decode(), re.M).group(0)
...         print("Card UID={}".format(card_uid))
...     except AttributeError:
...         pass
...
Card UID=09 DF 98 B3
```

Comment: Running it just like the given code it is running fine. But when I combine it with my code I get an error ```File "ardu.py", line 14, in <module>
    card_uid = re.search('(?<=Card UID: ).*', pieces.decode(), re.M).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'```

Comment: That's because the regex didn't match and as so the `group` method call throws an exception. Now I see that you've a while True and that the data keeps coming on that. I'll change my answer in accordance with it.

Comment: Fixed. You need to replace your `print` line with the whole `try`/`except` block from my answer. And within this `try`/`except` block, you need to replace `line.decode()` with `pieces.decode()`.